# Plot years on top of one another without converting from date format

Tags: r, date, datetime, ggplot2

I'm trying to use ggplot to plot 2 years of data on top of one another. I have unique datapoints for each week of the year (n), and can achieve the desired 'look' quite easily if I extract the week number from my date column and plot that to the x-axis:

```
data %>%
      mutate(week = week(date)) %>%
      ggplot() +
        geom_area(data = . %>% filter(year(date)==2022), aes(x = week, y = n), fill = 'grey70', alpha=0.2) +   
        geom_line(data = . %>% filter(year(date)==2023), mapping = aes(x = week, y = n), color = "#02ACDC")
```

[image]

However, I want to use `scale_x_datetime` on the x-axis so that the 'month' labels are displayed instead of the week number. I can't apply this to the extracted week number, and so I've tried to replicate the above plot *without* extracting the week number (and instead simply using the date column). However, I am unable to achieve a plot where the different years are stakced on top of one another:

```
    data %>%
      mutate(year=year(date)) %>%
      ggplot(group=year) +
        geom_area(data = . %>% filter(year==2022), aes(x=date, y=n), fill='grey70', alpha=0.2) + 
        geom_line(data = . %>% filter(year==2023), mapping = aes(x=date, y=n), color = "#02ACDC")+
        scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%b"))
```

[image]

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

---

Reproducible data:

```
data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1641081600, 1641686400, 1642291200, 
1642896000, 1643500800, 1644105600, 1644710400, 1645315200, 1645920000, 
1646524800, 1647129600, 1647734400, 1648339200, 1648944000, 1649548800, 
1650153600, 1650758400, 1651363200, 1651968000, 1652572800, 1653177600, 
1653782400, 1654387200, 1654992000, 1655596800, 1656201600, 1656806400, 
1657411200, 1658016000, 1658620800, 1659225600, 1659830400, 1660435200, 
1661040000, 1661644800, 1662249600, 1662854400, 1663459200, 1664064000, 
1664668800, 1665273600, 1665878400, 1666483200, 1667088000, 1667692800, 
1668297600, 1668902400, 1669507200, 1670112000, 1670716800, 1671321600, 
1671926400, 1672531200, 1673136000, 1673740800, 1674345600, 1674950400, 
1675555200, 1676160000, 1676764800, 1677369600, 1677974400, 1678579200, 
1679184000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    n = c(64L, 419L, 560L, 450L, 386L, 316L, 418L, 351L, 311L, 
    478L, 253L, 298L, 215L, 169L, 134L, 115L, 176L, 121L, 132L, 
    135L, 148L, 118L, 135L, 203L, 120L, 137L, 100L, 101L, 87L, 
    94L, 94L, 177L, 132L, 70L, 127L, 92L, 226L, 234L, 519L, 657L, 
    545L, 487L, 710L, 471L, 336L, 380L, 396L, 354L, 340L, 190L, 
    139L, 52L, 74L, 479L, 587L, 390L, 624L, 750L, 816L, 682L, 
    371L, 368L, 236L, 39L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -64L), groups = structure(list(
    date = structure(c(1641081600, 1641686400, 1642291200, 1642896000, 
    1643500800, 1644105600, 1644710400, 1645315200, 1645920000, 
    1646524800, 1647129600, 1647734400, 1648339200, 1648944000, 
    1649548800, 1650153600, 1650758400, 1651363200, 1651968000, 
    1652572800, 1653177600, 1653782400, 1654387200, 1654992000, 
    1655596800, 1656201600, 1656806400, 1657411200, 1658016000, 
    1658620800, 1659225600, 1659830400, 1660435200, 1661040000, 
    1661644800, 1662249600, 1662854400, 1663459200, 1664064000, 
    1664668800, 1665273600, 1665878400, 1666483200, 1667088000, 
    1667692800, 1668297600, 1668902400, 1669507200, 1670112000, 
    1670716800, 1671321600, 1671926400, 1672531200, 1673136000, 
    1673740800, 1674345600, 1674950400, 1675555200, 1676160000, 
    1676764800, 1677369600, 1677974400, 1678579200, 1679184000
    ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
        14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
        25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
        36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
        47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
        58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -64L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going wrong by expecting different years to overlap on `scale_x_datetime`. Dates in 2023 will always be plotted to the right of 2022.

This means you have two options. If you want to keep using `scale_x_datetime` then you need to change the data from one of the years so that the years match:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(date, n)) +
  geom_area(data = . %>% filter(year(date)==2022),
            fill = 'grey70', alpha = 0.2) +   
  geom_line(data = . %>% 
              filter(year(date) == 2023) %>%
              mutate(date = date - lubridate::years(1)),
            color = "#02ACDC") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = '%b')
```

[image]

Your other option is to stick to using week numbers, but convert the week number to a month name in a labelling function inside `scale_x_continuous`

```r
data %>%
  mutate(week = week(date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = week, y = n)) +
  geom_area(data = . %>% filter(year(date) == 2022), 
            fill = 'grey70', alpha = 0.2) +   
  geom_line(data = . %>% filter(year(date)==2023), color = "#02ACDC") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:12 * 4.5, 
                     labels = ~ format(as.Date('2022-01-01') + 7 * .x, '%b'))
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice - thanks! Since my issue is centered around the labels of this particular plot, I'm going to go with Option 2.